# Changing bar & chain on Husqvarna chainsaw

Tags: chain-saw

The original bar and chain that came with the chainsaw had 38cm length, 0.325" pitch, and 1.5mm gauge.

Can I change them with a 45cm length, 0.325" pitch, and **1.3mm** gauge?

I know the length is within the limits of the chainsaw, but I don't if gauge can be different

Answer (score 1):

Without know the model # I can not give you the exact answer, but this can get you as close as you can with the said info.

This shows all compatible sizes for Husqvarna chainsaws
https://www.baileysonline.com/Pages/Chainsaw-Chain-Cross-Reference-Chart/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on chainsaw model. On some model of Husqvarna chainsaw, you can change the bar length and chain setting(pitch/gauge), on some model you cannot.

But in most cases, you can use a smaller or larger bar than the stock bar size. Check the manual or product description in online.